# Best practice for keeping track of Callback result codes in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a Facebook application that uses many calls to Facebook's asynchrunner class.  As such, I am constantly using many callback listeners.. I have many classes that have to respond.  I am finding that I cannot remember which classes are defining which callback listener result codes.  I am worried that I am going to end up using the same callback result code in two different classes and this could cause serious problems.  What is the best practice for organizing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably meant "request codes", but it doesn't matter for the purpose of this answer.  I would suggest creating a separate interface to contain all these codes:

```
public interface FBCallbackCodes {
    public final static int AUTH_CODE = 1;
    public final static int POST_PHOTO_CODE = 2;
    ...
}
```

Then, whenever you need to introduce a new code, just add another `public final static` to this interface and use it like `FBCallbackCodes.AUTH_CODE` rather than hard-coding the values where you're using them.

This way you're achieving two things:

1. All codes are kept in one place and you'll easily see what else to add without introducing duplication.
2. If you have two places in your app that use the same functionality with the same code, you can easily see that the required code already exists and just re-use it.

Comment: Awesome.. That is exactly what I was looking for.  I figured there was a way to do this that wasn't addressed or used (obviously) in the millions of tutorials found on the net that cover only 1-3 classes.